# Printing a list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, feedparser

I am using feedparser to pull some data from a news channel RSS page.
There are around 54 title in the page.
However I want to print for example 10 details.
I tried over and over but i couldn't do that.

Could you help me.

```
import feedparser

url = ('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/turkce/rss.xml')
details = feedparser.parse(url)

def news(d):
  n = 0
  for i in d:
    n+=1
    print(n , '.news ')
    print(i.title)
    print(i.link)
    print(' ')

news(details.entries)
```

You can see the code on live and try:

```
https://repl.it/repls/AppropriateSufficientMaps#main.py
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it just printing a slice of the entries that you are having trouble with? You can try: `news(details.entries[:10])`

Comment: By the way, i want to print the first 10 titles or 10 random titles, it doesn't matter, i just mean i don't want to print all the pulled titles. thanks again..

Comment: You can put a `if n == 10: break` before the loop. Thus the loop is exited as soon as the value 10 is reached.

Comment: Thank you all, i tried the all reponse and they worked. Sometimes we need to think more simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to check if it needs to print out more of the items.

```
import feedparser

url = ('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/turkce/rss.xml')
details = feedparser.parse(url)

def news(d):
  n = 0
  for i in d:
    n+=1
    if n < 10:
        print(n , '.news ')
        print(i.title)
        print(i.link)
        print(' ')
    else:
        break

news(details.entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that :

By doing a slice directly in the function :

```
def news(d):
  n = 0
  for i in d[:10]:
    n+=1
    print(n , '.news ')
    print(i.title)
    print(i.link)
    print(' ')

news(details.entries)
```

Or when you call the function

```
def news(d):
  n = 0
  for i in d:
    n+=1
    print(n , '.news ')
    print(i.title)
    print(i.link)
    print(' ')

news(details.entries[:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution**

```
import feedparser
url = ('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/turkce/rss.xml')
details = feedparser.parse(url)
def news(d):
    for i in range(1,11):
    print(i,'.news','\n',d[i].title,'\n',d[i].link,end="\n\n")
news(details.entries)
```